# Is there a way to play a video with JS, that isn't play()?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I need to be able to press a button and play an embedded video. This would be easy, however, I need the method to be *compatible with IE4* (yes, that was launched in 1997). It's for a school project, and one of the requirements is to work on the school's system (which uses IE4).

I would be able to just use `play()`, but this requires IE9+.
Is there another way to play a video with a button, excluding `play()`?

Comment: IE4 doesn't support the video tag at all, regardless of method. If you're lucky you can find a twenty year old flash player that works, but I doubt it.

Comment: What format are the videos you want to play?

Comment: What sort of sadistic requirement is that? Renegotiate your position, ASAP

Comment: I'm not sure this task is even possible.

Comment: @adeneo and others - well, it's probably a High School or similar institution... probably not in the cards to renegotiate anything. But agreed, requiring IE4 support in 2016 should be banned as cruel and unusual punishment. (If it's a University and an IT-centric program, though, then yes, leave immediately)

Comment: @adeneo the school has a flash player that is compatible with IE4, I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: @Clive I've asked my teacher countless times if I have to make it for IE4 but she seems to think it's pretty normal. Everyone else makes their websites in the first version of dreamweaver...

Comment: @hpq wow, as in a Macromedia version? That's nuts :) Send her [here](http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/), it'll be perfect for her. Bravo for taking a positive approach to a ridiculous situation, good luck!

Comment: To use IE4 for *anything* now is really crazy - it doesn't even get essential security updates any more. As a student, there's probably nothing you can do (and maybe shouldn't even try, depending on what kind of person she is) but even IE6 has been long phased out. Maybe a Wikipedia link helps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_6

Comment: Also https://www.thestar.com/business/2016/01/10/microsoft-to-phase-out-support-for-older-versions-of-internet-explorer.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the `<video>` tag, which is what interfaces with JavaScript's `play()` method, is a part of HTML5 which is not supported by IE4. Honestly, this is what Flash was made for.

Comment: Oddly the video tag works? Nothing else HTML5 works though -_-